# Uniform limit of differentiable functions in higher dimension

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Let $U$ be a non empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \geq 1)$.
I do not assume any other properties on this set (not necessarily bounded, connected, etc.).

Is the following property always true ?

$$
\left.\begin{array}{l}
C^1(U) \ni f_k \rightarrow f \text{ in } C^0(U), \\
Df_k \rightarrow g \text{ in } C^0(U), \\
\end{array}\right\}
\Longrightarrow f \in C^1(U) \text{ and } Df=g,
$$

(the functions $f_k,f$ are real-valued).

For instance, it is true for connected $U$. What if it is not connected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is a 'local property'. You only have to show that the conclusion holds at each point. Take an open disk around the point contained in $U$ and apply the result to the disk.

Comment: True ! So this directly follows from the "bounded connected" case. Many thanks.